# one word recaptcha?

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

hello i see facebook is using recaptcha, but somehow in their register page, they can show one word of captcha instead of two, and then i notice that repcatcha validate only the first word, and the second word acts as a dummy, the question is **can we somehow tell the recaptcha to just show one word** ? rather then two ?

Answer (score 2):

[No](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore).

> But if a computer can't read such a
>   CAPTCHA, how does the system know the
>   correct answer to the puzzle? Here's
>   how: **Each new word that cannot be
>   read correctly by OCR is given to a
>   user in conjunction with another word
>   for which the answer is already
>   known**. The user is then asked to
>   read both words. If they solve the one
>   for which the answer is known, the
>   system assumes their answer is correct
>   for the new one. The system then gives
>   the new image to a number of other
>   people to determine, with higher
>   confidence, whether the original
>   answer was correct.

Comment: so facebook doesnt use recaptcha ?