# reCAPCTHA alternatives?

Tags: recaptcha

Just wondering if there are any good altervatives to reCAPTCHA? The reason I'm looking for alternative is I prefer 1 word instead of two words as given by reCAPTCHA. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768672/one-word-recaptcha

Answer (score 0):

one you could be trying is MyCaptcha  http://mycaptcha.codeplex.com/releases/view/34719